# C# TcpClient closes XNA game window after sending data

Tags: c#, tcp, xna, tcpclient, networkstream

I want to write multi player game in XNA 4. For sending data I am using TcpClient class connected like this:

```
try{
  client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
}
catch (Exception ex){
  Console.WriteLine("not connected");
  return;
}

if (!client.Connected) return;

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

stream.BeginRead(buf, 0, 1024, new AsyncCallback(PrijmiData), null);
```

when I want to send data with his methods:

```
private void Send(byte[] co){
  NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
  clientStream.BeginWrite(co, 0, co.Length, new AsyncCallback(Sended), null);
}

private void Sended(IAsyncResult res){
  NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
  clientStream.EndWrite(res);
}
```

Server receives data but XNA game is immediately ended. Why? Thank you for advice.

Comment: Your question is too vague. You ask about your XNA game, yet you provide no code, related to game itself. My best guess is - there is an unhandled exception throw somewhere, when you recieve/send a request.

Comment: @Nik exception is not thrown, Visual studio should be able to detect it, or I am wrong?

Comment: It depends on your settings

Comment: @Nik I have normal not edited setting I think EDIT: I surrounded both sending methods with try-catch no exception is thrown

Comment: May I suggest using the actual `Socket` object and keeping a connection alive between server and client at all times? If you're going to about it this way you'll open and close the stream every time you send something through it I think, which isn't what you'll want to do for a game.

Comment: @aevitas socket is created only once and then is used for sending data, after first send of data program is unexpectedly shutdown...

Comment: @Vodáček Probably because the connection is being closed and disposed of. If you want to create a true multiplayer game that sends and receives information on a regular basis, you'll need to keep that connection open at all times.

Comment: @aevitas I don't think that connection is closed, I am doing exactly what you are trying to explain, open channel and have it prepared for sending and then ONLY send data when the right time comes :-)

Comment: Alright. Well, there's no real way to tell why the game would be closing without some more specifics on how the game actually works. You should be able to find out why it's exiting through debugging quite easily though.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you are dealing with asynchronous things like this, applications don't throw proper exceptions even though they happen.

Have you tried stepping through the code to see when it actually closes?

My bet would be in the Sended-method. Try changing it like this, to see any exceptions (it's spelled "Sent", btw):

```
private void Sended(IAsyncResult res)  
{  
    try  
    {  
      NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();  
      clientStream.EndWrite(res);  
    }   
    catch (Exception ex)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(ex);  
    }  
}
```